# Google Tag Manage - to use or not to use

Tags: seo, google-analytics

I was interested in know the feedback from those who have used Google Tag Manager on WordPress. Basically, I want to know the advantages of implementing Google Tag Manager. Till now I have been using Yoast and Google Analytics WordPress plugin and they have been serving me well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason to change if all is working fine as it is, and you don't need to add anything new supported by tag manger. I use my own plugin to integrate analytics and few other things, and I don't plan to waste time doing exactly the same thing using different tools, and I am yet to see any proof that tag manager is better solution. It is more convenient, and you can decide to use it when building new site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Milan. I was of the same opinion. Do not try to fix something that is not broken but was not sure if it was the way to go.